# How To Start Jetty Properly

Tags: java, ssh, jetty

this really silly question probably, as no one else seems to be having this problem. In the Jetty documentation it says `jar -jar start.jar` starts Jetty, and it does. But when I close my SSH console, obviously it dies.

How do I run it PROPERLY?

Comment: I'm not sure of the *proper* answer, but a okay workaround is to just run it in a [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) session.

Comment: first step is to define "properly"

Comment: Sory, it would have been better to ask how to run it in the background. By properly I meant how most people do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use `nohup`

```
nohup java -jar start.jar
```

This has the advantage of writing stdout and stderr to a file

Another way would be to use `screen`

Comment: With nohup/screen how do I stop it?

Comment: @Matt, with nohup, you can kill the process with `kill`. with screen you reconnect to the screen session and stop it the usual way (ctrl-c or similar)

Comment: make sure to add "&" at the end to run it in the background `nohup java -jar start.jar &`

Answer (score 14):

Is this for running on a production machine that will actually serve up an application running under Jetty? I assume this is the case, since you're asking about starting it **properly**.

If so, you need a proper process supervision system, such as [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/), [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html), [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/), [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/), [systemd](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd), or good ol' [SysV init.d](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init#SysV-style) (as mentioned w/ [a gist](https://gist.github.com/404672)). Which to use depends on your preferences, business needs, and often, your underlying operating system.

I use and prefer [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/). It is built on [solid principles](http://smarden.org/runit/benefits.html) (daemontools), and for my preferred distribution (Debian and Ubuntu) it is [nicely](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=runit) [packaged](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=runit) by the author himself.

Despite being recommended in other answers, and mentioned in comments, starting a long running process in screen/tmux, or via nohup is sub-optimal. You don't have any real control over the process. It won't be restarted if it dies. You have to manually find its PID and otherwise manually manage the service. You have to do more manual work to get the log output (redirection, sending to some random file, etc). You cannot reliably make it depend on other processes, or have other processes depend on it. Decent process supervision systems provide all this functionality for you by default.

If your goal is something else entirely, then please update the question to be more specific about your use case.

Answer (score 3):

```
java -jar start.jar &
```

(to run in the background) should also work, though logging won't be transmuted as nice as w/nohup.

This is because killing the shell that started a process (e.g. by logging out) will kill process to unless they're background processes. Screen works since as well since it runs in the background, and screen effectively keeps your session running while you attach/detach.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on a *nix system, the best solution is may be using a script in `/etc/init.d` (or whatever your system's equivalent is). There's one at https://gist.github.com/404672.

Otherwise, using `nohup` or `screen` from the command-line will at least have the process not die when you log out. So will putting the process in the background with `&`.